# cmake does not generate makelists

Tags: c++, cmake

```
//CmakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (HelloWorld)

add_executable (HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp)

//HelloWorld.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
        cout<<"hw"<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I execute cmake.  No makefile is generated.
The file shown in the figure below is generated. Why is it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake has different generators, you can generate builds in different ways such as through 'make' or 'ninja' or through Visual Studio. You have most likely generated through Visual Studio and hence you have the Visual studio project `HelloWorld.sln`

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html